# PDF viewer partially fails to render image on retina screen

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js in my web application to render pdf files.

I’ve noticed that the viewer partially fails to render image only when the devicePixelRatio is greater than 1.

My goal is to render pdf files while keeping the devicePixelRatio.

Please help.

PDF.js version:
Stable (v2.1.266)

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<div class="pdf-viewer">
  <div id="pageContainer" class="pdf-page"></div>
</div>
```

index.js

```
pdfjsLib.workerSrc = '/vendor/assets/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js'
var pdfDoc;
var scale = 1;

var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
  url: #{pdf-url},
  cMapUrl: '/cmaps/',
  cMapPacked: true
})

loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf){
  pdfDoc = pdf;
  var viewer = document.getElementById('pageContainer')
  for(page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if(page == pdf.numPages){
      canvas.className =  'pdf-page-canvas d-block m-auto'
    }else{
      canvas.className =  'pdf-page-canvas d-block m-auto pb-2'
    }
    viewer.appendChild(canvas);
    renderPage(page, canvas, viewer)
  }
})

function renderPage(pageNum, canvas, container){
  pdfDoc.getPage(pageNum).then(function(page){
    var originalViewPort = page.getViewport({scale: scale})
    var aspectScale;
    var isLandscape = true;
    if(originalViewPort.height > originalViewPort.width){
      isLandscape = false;
    }
    if(isLandscape){
      aspectScale = Math.max((container.clientWidth / originalViewPort.width), (container.clientHeight / originalViewPort.height))
    }else{
      aspectScale = Math.min((container.clientWidth / originalViewPort.width), (container.clientHeight / originalViewPort.height))
    }
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: aspectScale})
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.width = (originalViewPort.width * aspectScale) * window.devicePixelRatio
    canvas.height = (originalViewPort.height * aspectScale) * window.devicePixelRatio        
    canvas.style.width = String(originalViewPort.width * aspectScale) + "px";
    canvas.style.height = String(originalViewPort.height * aspectScale) + "px";
    ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio,window.devicePixelRatio)  
    page.render({canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport});
  })
}
```

Screenshot of expected behavior:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SONQW.png)

Screenshot of actual behavior:
 [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPMdd.png)